# Power consumption in Arithmetic Operation in Arduino UNO

Tags: arduino-uno, atmega328

I would like to know how much current is consumed by multiplication operation in Arduino (ATMega328P) microcontroller. As per ATMega328p datasheet, multiplication operation takes 2 cycles. I have to now convert it to current.

Please let me know how to calculate it. Attached is ATMega328p datasheet for frequency versus current graph.

[image]

Comment: Did you try dividing?

Comment: I very much doubt it will be measurable compare to everything else going on in the chip.

Comment: Arduino is 8-bit microcontroller run by 8 MHZ clock frequency. So, to determine the period of the microcontroller clock, use equation as below:
Period (T) = 1/f = 1/ (8*10^6) = 0.125µs
Execution time (t) = C * T = 2 cycle * 0.125µs                                                                 Energy (E) = V * I * t = 5.5 *6mA(from above fiigure) * 2*0.125µs                                                                                      Please help me to correct if that above concept is correct or not

Comment: I think you'll find the Uno runs at 16MHz, not 8Mz, and 5V, not 5.5V.

Comment: Okay...if I change that ...everthing else is ok ?

Comment: Well, it doesn't tell you how much power the multiply operation uses, only how much power is used by the entire chip during the time it takes to execute a multiply operation.

Comment: I think that should be fine.Basically, I need to calculate the energy consumption for my encoder which has few multiplication operation and addition operation. Similarly I can calculate for addition too.

Comment: Did you read about what the "P" stands for in ATmega328p? PicoPower. The chip energy consumption depends on frequency and voltage (as in the diagram above). As most hardware design consumes energy on transitions it is not realistic to try to isolate the energy requirements for the instruction set (the processor core) as there are so many other activities (transitions) going on, e.g. clocks, timers, bus, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The power consumed by the chip won't change much by multiplying (compared to, say, adding). The chip is always fetching and executing instructions, unless you have put it into one of its sleep modes.

The only power consumption change would be if the instruction had a side-effect on a peripheral. For example, turning on the ADC unit (for analog reading), or by setting an output pin high or low.

Having said that, I set up a couple of tests and measured the power consumption. I didn't use a Uno because the power used by the "power on" LED and the voltage regulator tend to swamp the power consumption of the chip itself. However it was tested on an Atmega328P.

---

### Addition

#### Test sketch

```
volatile int foo = 100;
int main (void)
  {
  DDRB = 0b00111111;  // all ports to output
  DDRC = 0b00111111;
  DDRD = 0b11111111;
  PORTB = 0;          // write LOW
  PORTC = 0;
  PORTD = 0;

  while (true)
    foo += 42;
  }
```

#### Generated code

```
  a6:   80 91 00 01     lds r24, 0x0100
  aa:   90 91 01 01     lds r25, 0x0101
  ae:   8a 96           adiw    r24, 0x2a   ; 42
  b0:   90 93 01 01     sts 0x0101, r25
  b4:   80 93 00 01     sts 0x0100, r24
  b8:   f6 cf           rjmp    .-20        ; 0xa6 <main+0x10>
```

#### Measured consumption

I measured an average of 7.00 mA.

---

### Multiplication

#### Test sketch

```
volatile int foo = 100;
int main (void)
  {
  DDRB = 0b00111111;  // all ports to output
  DDRC = 0b00111111;
  DDRD = 0b11111111;
  PORTB = 0;          // write LOW
  PORTC = 0;
  PORTD = 0;

  while (true)
    foo *= 42;
  }
```

#### Generated code

```
  a6:   4a e2           ldi r20, 0x2A   ; 42
  a8:   20 91 00 01     lds r18, 0x0100
  ac:   30 91 01 01     lds r19, 0x0101
  b0:   42 9f           mul r20, r18
  b2:   c0 01           movw    r24, r0
  b4:   43 9f           mul r20, r19
  b6:   90 0d           add r25, r0
  b8:   11 24           eor r1, r1
  ba:   90 93 01 01     sts 0x0101, r25
  be:   80 93 00 01     sts 0x0100, r24
  c2:   f2 cf           rjmp    .-28        ; 0xa8 <main+0x12>
```

#### Measured consumption

I measured an average of 6.32 mA.

---

### Conclusion

I found this rather surprising, that it used less power doing a multiplication compared to an addition. Setting all ports to output and low was intended to remove any side-effects from spurious inputs on the input ports.

Still, as you can see from the generated code, most of the instructions are "helper" instructions (like loading from registers, storing to registers, looping etc.).

I'm still not sure I believe the results, perhaps someone else would like to try to reproduce them?

### Update

As Edgar Bonet pointed out, the multiplication test became zero after 14 iterations and thus it gave the processor the simpler task of multiplying by zero. I changed the multiplier to 41 which does not become zero. This time the average consumption was 7.34 mA which was higher than the addition test.

Comment: It is worth noting that, after 14 iterations, `foo` is zero in your multiplication test. Also, this test spends 47% of its time doing memory access, v.s. 67% for the addition test. I would expect memory accesses to cost more energy than arithmetics, as you are loaded by the stray capacitance of the whole data bus. But then, if you only read and write zeros, you never charge that stray cap.

Comment: @EdgarBonet Good catch! See amended answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just measure the current drawn by the board and an empty loop vs. a loop that does some multiplication? (other than 1,2,4,8..)

Comment: Is there any simpler way to measure current? I have digital USB multi-meter   purchased from http://www.ebay.ca/itm/like/172750787230?chn=ps&dispItem=1. I am powering from the USB port of this usb multimeter adapter but current is always same in all cases. Please let me know.

Comment: That device can only measure current in 10mA increments. You probably need something that can measure uA or better. A decent VOM or a bench top multi meter for example.

Comment: Okay. What will be the probe pins in Arduino Micro-controller in case we have to use multi meter othan USB multi-meter?

Comment: Use the 5V supply pin and connect the meter is series.

Comment: you mean 5V pin of arduino to multimeter's +ve terminal and GND of Arduino to multimeter's GND right?

Comment: [Like this](https://usercontent1.hubstatic.com/6725028_f520.jpg) Better yet, google 'how to measure current' before you break something.

Comment: Hey! For current measurements you have to move your red probe to hole marked with A, uA and/or mA, or you will shorcut something

Comment: SO, if I measure current at 5V pin of arduino using multimeter (in range of micro amper), then I can compute the power consumption as below. Is this understanding correct? Arduino Uno R3 run by 16 MHZ clock frequency. So, to determine the period of the microcontroller clock, use equation as below: Period (T) = 1/f = 1/ (16*10^6) = 0.0625µs Execution time (t) = C * T = 2 cycle * 0.0625µs Energy (E) = V * I * t = 5*(measure current at 5V) * (2*0.0625)µs

Comment: I could NOT read micro ampere current at 5V power point. While measuring current via digital multi-meter, the mills-ampere current is showing reading as "1." So, in the equation E=V * I *t (E = V * I * t = 5*10mA * (2*0.0625)µs, if I put I as 10mA, does that mean current taken by entire chip not Arithmetic operations, right?

Comment: Is there any way to determined the current or energy consumed while performing instruction sets (e.g. addition, multiplication, subtraction etc) in ATMega328P?